# store a number of list together in rows so i can call every row and make manipulations

Tags: python, list

I want to store a number of list together. I store my randomly generated 
    coordinates in an array.(identity , x, y, z) (1,2,3,0)(2,1,0,6)............
    (n,4,8,3)..... I want these all rows to be contained in a list so that i can 
    subtract the coordinates of 3 identity from 2 or from 2 to 1st . i am new to 
    python. now if 8 rows are generated they are not together. This is only part 
    of code, i also generate random numbers and store them. information is the 
    array name where i store my data of coordinates generated randomly.

```
for i in range (0,8)   
    x = information [i,0] [0]
    y = information [i,0] [1]
    z = information [i,0] [2]
    list = [ i,x,y,z]
    print list
```

Comment: That is not valid python.

Comment: i know , this is just part of my code, i just need to ask how can i store multiple rows together so that i can perform airthmetic operations to my rows

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a list of lists:

```
from random import randint
points = []
for i in range(8):
    points.append([randint(0, 10) for i in range(3)])
# now possible to access point i by points[i]
print(points)
```

Outputs

```
[[8, 7, 7], [0, 6, 7], [10, 2, 6], [3, 3, 8], [4, 8, 0], [1, 9, 0], [1, 5, 0], [4, 7, 7]]
```